# A problem while making an api using ASP.Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

i am trying to make an angular application that takes an api made from asp.net core but while making the api , it didn't work and appear as planned and didn't know where was the problem...
I made an asp.net core web app.
This is the student.cs file made in the model folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI101.Model
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Pass { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the studentmanager also in model folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI101.Model
{
    public class StudentManager
    {
        public List<Student> GetResults()
        {
            List<Student> oList = new List<Student>();
            var r = new Random();
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var x = new Student();
                x.ID = i;
                x.Name = String.Format("Name{0}", i, ToString());
                x.Pass = (r.Next() % 2 == 0);
                oList.Add(x);
            }
            return oList;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that should return aaaaa

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI101.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("mariam")]
        public string test()
        {
            return "aaaaa";
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to launch the code and it didn't work as planned o the link:https://localhost:5001/api/Student/mariam

Comment: You need to explain what "didn’t work as planned" means. Are there errors? Messages? What does and doesn’t happen?

Comment: Change `[Route("mariam")]` to `[HttpGet, Route("mariam")]`. Then change `public string test()` to `public IActionResult test()`. Then change `return "aaaaa";` to `return Ok("aaaaa");`

Comment: @Andy it didn't work ,nothing appeared

Comment: @sellotape it gives locale host page can't be found

Comment: Try and replace the Route attribute on the controller with RoutePrefix

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are using [Route("mariam")] which overrides the controller route.

You need to use [HttpGet("mariam")] instead.

```
    [HttpGet("mariam")]
    public string test()
    {
        return "aaaaa";
    }
```

Using HttpGet will add to the controller route.

Comment: and the link should be the same??

Comment: if the same link it didn't work it gives me local host page can't be found

Comment: in the console it gives this error : "(index):5551 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated."

Comment: @AdibAkkari i am pretty sure that's how it works. I have developed dozens of apis. You still have not showed how you map your controllers in your startup.  I even created a small project and it works with the same link.

Comment: @AdibAkkari about that error.... that is not an asp.net core error.

Comment: and what to do now ?

Comment: @AdibAkkari you still have not posted your Startup.cs.... The policy in stackoverflow is that you need to post a fully reproducible example.  Also if the link works in the browser but not from the Angular app then perhaps you need to ask another question for the angular problem.  Please post your Startup.cs class and also please post a picture of what you get in the browser when you navigate to "https://localhost:5001/api/Student/mariam"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380858/asp-net-api-not-appearing

Comment: this is the new question

Comment: You just created the same question again.... You should close this question or delete it.  Duplicate questions are not allowed