# Asp.net API not appearing

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

i am trying to make an angular application that takes an api made from asp.net core but while making the api , it didn't work and appear as planned and didn't know where was the problem...
I made an asp.net core web app.
This is the student.cs file made in the model folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI101.Model
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Pass { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the studentmanager also in model folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI101.Model
{
    public class StudentManager
    {
        public List<Student> GetResults()
        {
            List<Student> oList = new List<Student>();
            var r = new Random();
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var x = new Student();
                x.ID = i;
                x.Name = String.Format("Name{0}", i, ToString());
                x.Pass = (r.Next() % 2 == 0);
                oList.Add(x);
            }
            return oList;
        }
    }
}
```

This is startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI101
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that should return aaaaa

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI101.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("mariam")]
        public string test()
        {
            return "aaaaa";
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to launch the code and it didn't work as planned o the link:https://localhost:5001/api/Student/mariam

While running the application on the previous link it appeared like that:
[browser status after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khqgm.png)

This is the lanchsettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40854",
      "sslPort": 44361
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebAPI101": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/Student/mariam",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try looking your launchsettings.json. It may be that the port numbers are misconfigured.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A problem while making an api using ASP.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67373657/a-problem-while-making-an-api-using-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration is missing `AddControllers` and `MapControllerRoute` calls. Checkout the example below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebAPI101
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    "default",
                    "api/{controller}/{action=Index}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should i add a new controller named MapControllerRoute.cs and paste the same code  ?

Comment: No checkout the example, you need to invoke `endpoints.MapControllerRoute(` in the `Configure` method

Comment: didn't get it what should i change in endpoints.MapControllerRoute(    ???

Comment: You can copy and paste `endpoints.MapControllerRoute...` into your `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>` invocation. It should be below the ` endpoints.MapRazorPages();` you currently have

Comment: Great! Good luck!